# Change excel cell background every x seconds

Tags: excel, cell

Hi anyway to change cell color every x seconds with a formula? Lets say now to be yellow after 5 seconds white and redo this task again

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved utilizing VBA.

To get a cell to blink every 5 seconds from yellow to white, the following code should be pasted into a new module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim RunTimer As Date

Sub ColorChange()
    RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    Application.OnTime RunTimer, "ColorChange"
    If Range("a1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
        Range("a1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Else
        Range("a1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

End Sub
```

In order to run this you can launch it from the macros menu, or set it up to start automatically when you open the workbook. If you would like the latter then make sure you copy the following code into the workbook code section:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Call ColorChange

End Sub
```

Additionally, in order to stop this macro, you will need to paste the following code under the original, allowing for you to stop the code when you choose. Again, you will be able to access this via the macros menu in order to run it.

```
Sub StopColor()

Application.OnTime RunTimer, "ColorChange", , False

End Sub
```